# Feeding a mathematical function as the argument of a Function

Tags: function-construction

I have the following Function:

```
Testing[g[x_], y_] := Module[{s = x, t = y, c }, c = s + t ; c]
```

Which I am just trying to get to work before doing my actual application. It should accept a function g[x] and do stuff with it.

As a test, I try:

```
f[x_] := x^2;
Testing[f[x], 4]
```

But it just returns

> Testing[x^2, 4]

which means that it does not understand what I mean...? What is the correct syntax to feed a mathematical function into my Function?

Comment: `Testing` will only work for something with head `g` while `f[x]` evaluates to `Power[x,2]`.

Comment: Why not just run `Testing[x_, y_]`?

Comment: If you want it to accept a function in the form `g[x]`, but with any kind of name (instead of `g` specifically) and any kind of variable, then you should use `Testing[g_[x_], y_] := ...`. Moreover, you should probably make `Testing` `HoldFirst` to keep the function from evaluating too early: `SetAttributes[Testing, HoldFirst]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you, what you want is that `c` becomes `x^2 + 4`. This gives you that polynomial with an anonymous variable instead of `x`:

```
Testing[g_, y_] := Module[{s = g[#], t = y, c}, c = Evaluate[s + t] &; c]
f[x_] := x^2
Testing[f, 4]
```

> 4 + #1^2 &